# How to change value of css attribute with watir-webdriver after page is loaded?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Example:

```
<div id="xxx" style="width: 76px; height: 302px; z-index: 0; text-align: left;">
```

I would like watir-wedriver to change `z-index: 0` to `z-index: -1` automatically, otherwise I have to do that manually in Firebug while script is sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute any javascript with something like this:

```
browser.execute_script "javascript_code"
```

I am not a javascript expert so you will have to figure out that part yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Željko, for idea!

The code that does the trick in this case is

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('xxx').style.zIndex='-1';")
```